# Visualforce Remoting Error

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

I am using Visualforce remoting to send data to a Remote Action method in my controller. The Remote Action method has a `Map<String, Object> args` parameter.

In the Remote Action method if I try to obtain a Map from the args map, then I get a "Visualforce Remoting Exception: undefined" error.

In other words, on the javascript side I have added an object to my params object:

```
params.myMap = {isActive: true, isNew: true};
params.nonMapValue = color: 'blue';
```

I do not get an error in the remote action until I try and obtain the value of the `myMap` key from the Map.

It is strange because I can put the map into system.debug and it will print out the whole map fine e.g.

```
{myMap={isActive=true, isNew=true}, nonMapValue=blue}
```

but I get an error when I try:

```
arguments.get('myMap');
```

Does anyone know why this is? This is not a casting issue because I am not trying to cast it yet.

Can anyone suggest a good way to be able to send over and use a javascript object to my Remote Action method?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the controller Method that you are using ? Also do specify the requirement that you have

Comment: I believe the issue is with the Map. When you are defining a remote Method, you actually are defining a webservice within salesforce and somehow i believe that Maps are not supported as part of your webservice.

Comment: Thanks Kaw. Yes. I think that must be the case, but it seems that if you define a class with the correct getters and setters and use that as the argument to the RemoteAction, then it will correctly parse maps.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this error by making the parameter of my Remote Action method a class which I define. Without changing the javascript in any way, the map is now correctly parsed and can be obtained as shown below.

**My Class**

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myNonMapValue;
    private Map<String, Boolean> myMap;

    public void setMyNonMapValue(String nmv) {
        this.nonMapValue = nmv;
    }

    public String getMyNonMapValue() {
        return nonMapValue;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<String, Boolean> m) {
        this.myMap = m;
    }

    public Map<String, Boolean> getMyMap() {
        return myMap
    }
}
```

**My Remote Action Method**

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<String> doWork(MyClass params) {

    String nonMapValue = params.getMyNonMapValue();
    Map<String, Boolean> myMap = params.getMyMap();
}
```

Comment: Also, you're missing the return in the doWork method

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `<ANY>` type is not supported in @RemoteAction method signatures. The JavaScript Remoting client throws an UnsupportedOperationError exception in these cases:

- `Object` won't work
- `List<Object>` won't work
- `Map<String,Object>` won't work unless all the map values are primitives

Using the apex class DTO as the parameter type is excellent. (Worth noting the implicit JSON de/serializer runs in strict mode and any properties not present in the DTO throw "Unknown Field")